# How to correctly delete an object in another thread

Tags: multithreading, haxe

Yesterday our teammate created code, where he moved query.destroy() to the separate thread. He did it in order to make code faster.

```
    private queryBag : IQueryBag
    ... ... ...
    private function destroyQueryBag() : Void
    {
        CoreThread.transferToCoreThread(function()
        {
            if (queryBag != null)
            {
                queryBag.destroy();
                queryBag = null;
            }
        });
    }

    private function resetRequestsAndResponses() : Void
    {
        destroyQueryBag();
        queryBag = null;
        queryBag = createNewQueryBag();
    }
```

But I found this code to Ricky. What if new thread invoke their code too late after creating NewQueryBag? In this case queryBag will be still null. I think that new thread should use another reference, and correct code should be like the next:

```
    private var queryBag : IQueryBag
    ... ... ...
    private function destroyQueryBag() : Void
    {
        private var tempQueryBag = queryBag; // another reference !!!
        queryBag = null;
        CoreThread.transferToCoreThread(function()
        {
            if (tempQueryBag != null)
            {
                tempQueryBag.destroy();
                tempQueryBag = null;
            }
        });
    }

    private function resetRequestsAndResponses() : Void
    {
        destroyQueryBag();
        queryBag = createNewQueryBag();
    }
```

I'm not enough experienced in multi-thread. Could any please confirm my assumptions?

Comment: I think your solution is better. I would remove the `tempQueryBag != null` check though, because `tempQueryBag` is not supposed to be null, and if for some reason it should ever become null before you get to destroy it, you actually want the null pointer exception, rather than quietly skipping the destroy call, which may lead to resource leakage.